# Clean way to do rewrite rules

Tags: haskell, dsl

I have the following toy language:

```
module Lang where

data Op = Move Int -- Move the pointer N steps
        | Add  Int -- Add N to the value under the pointer
        | Skip     -- Skip next op if the value under the pointer is 0
        | Halt     -- End execution
        deriving (Show, Eq)

type Program = [Op]
```

The language has a finite tape of memory cells that wraps around, and a pointer that points at some cell. All the cells are initially zero. The program is executed repeatedly until the halt instruction is read.

Now I would like to write a function that optimizes a given program. Here is the optimizations that I would like to perform:

```
| Original code       | Optimization   |
|---------------------|----------------|
| Move a : Move b : x | Move (a+b) : x |
| Add  a : Add  b : x | Add  (a+b) : x |
| Move 0 : x          | x              |
| Add  0 : x          | x              |
| Skip : Skip : x : y | x : y          |
| Halt : _            | Halt           |
```

Additionally, I can only do an optimization on code that is not directly after a skip, because doing that would change the meaning of the program.

Is repeatedly pattern matching on the list until no more optimizations can be performed really the best/cleanest way to do this?

What if I decide that I also want to perform more advanced rewrites like these:

```
| Original code                                          | Optimization                                   |
|--------------------------------------------------------|------------------------------------------------|
| if the program begins with (Skip : a)                  | move it to the end of the program              |
| Move x ++ no_skips : Move -x ++ no_skips' : Move w : q | Move x ++ no_skips ++ no_skips' : Move w-x : q |
```

Comment: The simplest way is to express each optimization (each line in the table) as a function `Program -> Maybe Program` (call this type `Opt`); you can express combinators on `Opt`, e.g. which apply an optimization until it fails, which apply an optimization at every node of the AST, try each given optimization in sequence, apply all the given optimizations, etc. `no_skips` is just a function `Program -> Maybe (Program, Program)`. For a more advanced approach, see [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata-0.11/docs/Data-Comp-TermRewriting.html).

Answer (score 2):

## Use Maybe's!

@user2407038 told me that I could use Maybe in a comment

```hs
module MaybeProg where

import Lang
import Control.Monad

type Opt = Program -> Maybe Program

optimize = untilFail step
  where step p | p' <- atEveryButSkipNextWhen (==Skip) rewrite
                     . atEvery   delNopSkip
                     $ untilFail moveSkips p
               , p /= p' = Just p'
               | otherwise = Nothing
        rewrite = tryAll [joinMoves, joinAdds, delNopMov, delNopAdd, termHalt, reorder]

joinMoves  p = do (Move a : Move b : x) <- pure p; Just $ Move (a+b) : x
joinAdds   p = do (Add  a : Add  b : x) <- pure p; Just $ Add  (a+b) : x
delNopMov  p = do (Move 0          : x) <- pure p; Just x
delNopAdd  p = do (Add  0          : x) <- pure p; Just x
delNopSkip p = do (Skip   : Skip   : x) <- pure p; Just x
termHalt   p = do (Halt            : _) <- pure p; Just [Halt]
moveSkips  p = do (Skip   : x : y  : z) <- pure p; Just $ y : z ++ [Skip, x]

reorder p = do
  (Move x : rst)      <- pure p
  (as, Move y : rst') <- break' isMove rst
  guard $ x == -y && all (/=Skip) as
  (bs, Move w :   q ) <- break' isMove rst'
  guard $ all (/=Skip) bs
  return $ Move x : as ++ bs ++ Move (w-x) : q
 where isMove (Move _) = True
       isMove _        = False

--------

untilFail :: Opt -> Program -> Program
untilFail o p | Just p' <- o p = untilFail o p'
              | otherwise   = p

atEvery :: Opt -> Program -> Program
atEvery o p | (x:xs) <- untilFail o p = x : atEvery o xs
            | otherwise               = []

atEveryButSkipNextWhen c o p@(h:_)
  | not $ c h
  , (x:xs) <- untilFail o p = x : atEveryButSkipNextWhen c o xs
  | (p1:p2:ps) <- p = p1:p2:atEveryButSkipNextWhen c o ps
  | otherwise = p
atEveryButSkipNextWhen _ _ [] = []

tryAll :: [Opt] -> Opt
tryAll os p = do
  Just x : _ <- pure . dropWhile (==Nothing) $ ($p) <$> os
  return x

break' f p | (x, y) <- break f p
           , not $ null y = Just (x, y)
           | otherwise = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use pattern matching!

This is what I wanted to avoid, I am posting it for reference

```hs
module Pattern where

import Lang


optimize :: Program -> Program
optimize p
  | p' <- reorder $ rewrite $ moveSkip p
  , p /= p'   = optimize p'
  | otherwise = p

rewrite :: Program -> Program
rewrite (Move a : Move b : x) = rewrite $ Move (a+b) : x
rewrite (Add  a : Add  b : x) = rewrite $ Add  (a+b) : x
rewrite (Move 0          : x) = rewrite x
rewrite (Add  0          : x) = rewrite x
rewrite (Skip   : Skip   : x) = rewrite x
rewrite (Halt            : _) = [Halt]
rewrite (Skip : x : xs) = Skip : x : rewrite xs
rewrite (x : xs)        = x : rewrite xs
rewrite []              = []

moveSkip :: Program -> Program
moveSkip (Skip : a : x) = x ++ [Skip, a]
moveSkip x = x

reorder :: Program -> Program
reorder (Move x : xs)
  | (no_skips  , Move y : xs') <- break isMove xs
  , (no_skips' , Move w :  q ) <- break isMove xs'
  , x == -y
  , all (/=Skip) no_skips
  , all (/=Skip) no_skips'
  = Move x : no_skips ++ no_skips' ++ Move (w-x) : reorder q
  | otherwise  = Move x : reorder xs
reorder (Skip : x : xs) = Skip : x : reorder xs
reorder (x:xs) = x : reorder xs
reorder []     = []

isMove (Move _) = True
isMove _        = False
```